# Why does str_replace not actually replace the text which should be replaced in PHP?

Tags: php

I've Googled for a while but haven't found any solution so far. I'm trying to replace some placeholders in a Word-document using PHP. All placeholders are replaced succesfully, except the DATE_PLACEHOLDER. See code below:

```
// De tickets aanmaken
                $zip = new ZipArchive;

                // Variablen declareren
                $file_to_modify = 'word/document.xml';
                $template_file = "ticket_template.docx";
                $new_file = 'ticket_to_mail.docx';

                // Kopie maken van de template om te bewerken
                copy($template_file,$new_file);

                if ($zip->open($new_file) === TRUE) {
                    // Bestand inlezen
                    $old_contents = $zip->getFromName($file_to_modify);
                    echo $old_contents . "<br>";
                    // Placeholders in het template invullen
                    $new_contents = str_replace('DISPLAYNAME_PLACEHOLDER', $displayname, $old_contents);
                    echo $new_contents . "<br>";
                    $new_contents = str_replace('DATE_PLACEHOLDER', $date, $new_contents); // NOT WORKING
                    echo $new_contents . "<br>";
                    $new_contents = str_replace('ROW_PLACEHOLDER', $row, $new_contents);
                    echo $new_contents . "<br>";
                    $new_contents = str_replace('SEAT_PLACEHOLDER', $seat, $new_contents);
                    echo $new_contents . "<br>";
                    $new_contents = str_replace('NAME_PLACEHOLDER', $fullname, $new_contents);
                    echo $new_contents . "<br>";
                    // Oude inhoud verwijderen
                    $zip->deleteName($file_to_modify);
                    // Nieuwe inhoud schrijven
                    $zip->addFromString($file_to_modify, $new_contents);
                    // Bestand opslaan
                    $return =$zip->close();
                    if ($return !== TRUE){
                        echo "Error: fout tijdens het bewerken van het ticket-template";
                    }
                } else {
                  echo "Error: fout tijdens het bewerken van het ticket-template";
                }
```

The $date variable is declared here: `$date = date('d-m-Y H:i', StrToTime($value['date']));`

I already tried echoing $date, checking that it's value is correct, which it is. Also, as you can see in the example above, I tried echoing the contents of the Word-document everytime I replaced something. This gave the following results:

```
right-1269100E-ticketDISPLAYNAME_PLACEHOLDER DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: ROW_PLACEHOLDER Stoel: SEAT_PLACEHOLDER NAME_PLACEHOLDERBedankt voor uw reservering voor DISPLAYNAME_PLACEHOLDER!
right-1269100E-ticketDen Hulster Musical DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: ROW_PLACEHOLDER Stoel: SEAT_PLACEHOLDER NAME_PLACEHOLDERBedankt voor uw reservering voor Den Hulster Musical!
right-1269100E-ticketDen Hulster Musical DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: ROW_PLACEHOLDER Stoel: SEAT_PLACEHOLDER NAME_PLACEHOLDERBedankt voor uw reservering voor Den Hulster Musical!
right-1269100E-ticketDen Hulster Musical DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: 1 Stoel: SEAT_PLACEHOLDER NAME_PLACEHOLDERBedankt voor uw reservering voor Den Hulster Musical!
right-1269100E-ticketDen Hulster Musical DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: 1 Stoel: 3 NAME_PLACEHOLDERBedankt voor uw reservering voor Den Hulster Musical!
right-1269100E-ticketDen Hulster Musical DATE_PLACEHOLDER Rij: 1 Stoel: 3 John JohnsonBedankt voor uw reservering voor Den Hulster Musical!
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change the tag name to for example #DATEPLACEHOLDER# and test again. See nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Grumpy Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this, and other alternative placeholders texts, but it still doesn't work. I also tried changing the $date variable to a simple string, to see if there was something wrong there, but this didn't work either. I really have no clue what is going on here.

Comment: EDIT: I just tried completely recreating the Word-file, and this seemed to have fixed the issue. No idea why it didn't work in the first place though.